# Andding 2nd Data Source to Spring Project causing field naming issues

Tags: spring, jpa

I have a Java 8 Spring Boot Rest Service (CrudRepository) project that until now, had ORACLE data source as only source.   As such, when I defined the entities, I only added @Column(name = "xxxx") as needed.   I basically followed the camelCase convention where there is _ in the Oracle Field Name.

I added a new data source MySql, and now the project has 2 data sources.   I put the appropriate config file for each DS.  All works well except after adding the 2nd DS, I am finding that I now need to put  @Column(name = "xxxx") on every entity field.

I would appreciate it if someone could point me to an explanation why this is needed.  After putting @Column(name = "xxxx")  every where, all works well, but why is this needed with multiple DS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally when I work with two or more ds, I separate entities in different packages like this:

DS1: com.example.entity
DS2: com.example.mysql.entity

And same way other packages repository/service/controller(com.example.mysql.repository...)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback ... I do same thing.   But still, unless I annotatate each field with @COLUMN(name="ABC_EDF" ... I get run time errors that field abcEdf is not recognized.   I don't have this problem if single source ... only in multiple sources situation.